# stop jquery code to run further in form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a options variable for the jquery form plugin.

It has a function beforeSubmit. Now i want to validate the form for which i want to stop the execution of the code.

How can i stop jQuery to run the code. Currently i m using throw "error" for example -

```
var options = { 
beforeSend: function(e) 
{
    $("#progress").show();
    //clear everything
    $("#bar").width('0%');
    $("#message").html("");
    $("#percent").html("0%");
    throw "error";
}, ....
```

Please see the example [here](http://nvoids.com/t1n.jsp)

Regards,

Comment: why are you trying to do this on beforesend. My guess is the purpose of this method is not to be used for validation but to notify user or such. I would validate before you call send.

Comment: Yes i m right now validating it before send, but the function(e), here the variable e is not supported because its not a jquery function. I m using something like if(a==1) { throw "error" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery form plugin has an option beforeSubmit like beforeSend...

```
beforeSubmit: function() {
    return validate();
}
```

validate() function should return a true to continue or a false to stop execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) option to stop propagation. 
In your case add `e.preventDefault();` in first line of your function.

Comment: nope that throws the error in the console e.preventDefault() is not a function.

Comment: `preventDefault` doesn't stop the propagation of an event. `stopPropagation` does this.

Comment: It returns - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stopPropagation'